# While creating dynamic url I am getting a Reverse for 'dashboard_group' with arguments error

Tags: python, django, url

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('processes/', views.processes, name="dashboard"),
    path('processes/<uuid:u_id>/', views.groups, name="dashboard_group")
]
```

views.py

```
def processes(request):
    return render(request, 'processes/index.html')

def groups(request, u_id):
    return render(request, 'create_instance/index.html')
```

The above code gives me following error - Reverse for 'dashboard_group' with arguments '('a21713b0ec29416c8fb27d4f339eabb8',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['processes\/(?P[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})\/$']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `uuid:` from the path. Your code should look like this.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('processes/', views.processes, name="dashboard"),
    path('processes/<u_id>/', views.groups, name="dashboard_group")
]
```

According to Django official documentation, the bracket may include a converter specification (like the `int` part of `<int:section>`) which limits the characters matched and may also change the type of the variable passed to the view.
[django.urls functions for use in URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/)